# how to set train batch size when using input_fn in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

In tensorflow `estimator/estimator.py`, function `fit`, `partial_fit`, `predict` and so on, it says that when using `input_fn`, `batch_size` must be None. 
So, where to set the batch_size. In my code, input_fn is needed because I use it to select some features from origin data. 
Thanks.